# Duplicate classes objects within solution

Tags: vb.net

Within my solution I have couple projects. One of them is for files downloading, second project is for parsing files and third one for loading to database. Inside Parse project I have those classes:

```
 Public Class AMS5520_CUISAMS
        Implements IDelimeted
        Implements IXml

        Private ReadOnly _config As GeneralSettingsSerializer
        Private ReadOnly _datasource As Datasource

    #Region "CONSTRUCTORS"
        Public Sub New(ByVal mygeneralConfig As GeneralSettingsSerializer, ByVal datasource As Datasource)
            _config = mygeneralConfig
            _datasource = datasource
        End Sub
    #End Region

        Public Sub Delimeted() Implements IDelimeted.Delimeted
'Delimeted class belongs to Parser project
            Dim del As New Delimeted(_config, _datasource)  
            del.Run()
        End Sub

        Public Sub Xml() Implements IXml.Xml
XML class belongs to Parser project
            Dim xml As New XML(_config, _datasource)
            xml.Run()
        End Sub

    End Class

    Public Class U2000
        Implements IDelimeted

        Private ReadOnly _config As GeneralSettingsSerializer
        Private ReadOnly _datasource As Datasource


    #Region "CONSTRUCTORS"
        Public Sub New(mygeneralConfig As GeneralSettingsSerializer, datasource As Datasource)
            _config = mygeneralConfig
            _datasource = datasource
        End Sub
    #End Region

        Public Sub Delimeted() Implements IDelimeted.Delimeted
            Dim del As New Delimeted(_config, _datasource)
            del.Run()
        End Sub

    End Class
```

Inside collect project I am using those classes:

```
Public Class AMS5520_CUISAMS
    Inherits Collect

#Region "CONSTRUCTORS"
    Public Sub New(mygeneralConfig As GeneralSettingsSerializer, datasource As Datasource)
        MyBase.New(mygeneralConfig, Datasource)
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class

Public Class U2000
    Inherits Collect

#Region "CONSTRUCTORS"
    Public Sub New(mygeneralConfig As GeneralSettingsSerializer, Datasource As Datasource)
        MyBase.New(mygeneralConfig, Datasource)
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class

Inside Loader project I have those two classes:

Public Class AMS5520_CUISAMS
    Inherits Load

#Region "CONSTRUCTORS"
    Public Sub New(mygeneralConfig As GeneralSettingsSerializer, datasource As Datasource)
        MyBase.New(mygeneralConfig, datasource)
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class

Public Class U2000
    Inherits Load

#Region "CONSTRUCTORS"
    Public Sub New(mygeneralConfig As GeneralSettingsSerializer, datasource As Datasource)
        MyBase.New(mygeneralConfig, datasource)
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

As you can see those classes are the same, and I wonder how to reduce it that somewhere I would have only it in one place and those three project could reference two it without duplication.

I have also Datasource project which contains Datasource enum which  I am using within those projects:

```
Public Enum Datasource
    AMS5520_CUISAMS
    SOEM
    U2000
    SAM_ESS_CFAN7450
    SAM_ESS_REN7450
End Enum
```

The first thing from my side was to put those classes inside Datasource project. I am using almost in all of my project Datasource enum. I got then a lot of indirect reference and other erros. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It sounds like VS is confused by a class with the same name in 3 projects, and I cant imagine your code would be less so.  From what is there, it seems like there could be one class which knows how to do things differently based on that Enum passed in the ctor.

Comment: These classes should be in the same namespace, and they should be named uniquely. That should then be compiled and imported into other projects.

Comment: @Plutonix: Exactly right now I have same two classes inside 3 different projects and I am looking way to make them inside one of project and delete inside rest but as I said I have problems. How can I do it in this particural case?